# Add a series column that will increment if reaches the maximum number

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to add a column that will count according to the max number of series.

I have generated the SERIES_NO column using below:

```
MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_code, loc_code, cargo_sts) - 1, 3) + 1
```

In this case the Max series no is `3`. Below is the sample result set. Now, I want to generate the `SHEET_NO` column. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
CARGO_STS   LOC_CODE    ITEM_CODE   AVAIL_QTY   SERIES_NO    SHEET_NO
NORMAL      D1867BD1    0000044500     6             1           1
NORMAL      D1947GD1    0000055401     2             2           1
NORMAL      D3351AA1    0000058000     2             3           1
NORMAL      D1945DC2    0000058201     1             1           2
STO-DAMAGE  205-12BB    0000058300     1             2           2
NORMAL      D3446FB1    0000058300     1             3           2
NORMAL      Q00-37CA    0000060401   128             1           3  
NORMAL      D1158FA1    0000079901    36             2           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like following will do:

```
ceil (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_code, loc_code, cargo_sts) /3 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Bhavesh. I found the correct way to do it.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara It would probably be better to use `CEIL` not `FLOOR`, since FLOOR (1/3) = 0, but it looks like Jeff wants it to be 1 which means you'd then have to add 1 to it afterwards. CEIL(1/3) would be 1, which negates the need to add one afterwards.